# Error loading file with full name containing spaces in directory with delphi

Tags: delphi, io, stream

I am using XE8, win 8.1.

When trying load a file with spaces in directory, I am getting a exception  of syntax name of the file or directory is invalid.
If I use imageen dialog to preview  the file, no erros are found.

I did two tests with the procedure load_file1 and load_file2 and I have the same problem.

Is there a wrokaround to solve it?

```
function get_file:string;
begin
 result:='"C:\Compartilhada\dicomserver versoes\dicomserverx\data\Genesis-1000\1.2.410.200013.1.215.1.200912141600580009_0001_000001_13061821270002.dcm"'
end;

procedure load_file1;
var fStm:Tstream;
    p1:string;
begin
          p1:=get_file;
          fStm := tFileStream.Create( p1, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone ); //->Error Here
          try
           TBlobField(FieldByName('dicom')).LoadFromStream(fStm);
           Post;
          finally
            fSTm.Free;
          end;
end;


procedure load_file2;
p1:string;
begin
           p1:=get_file;
           TBlobField(FieldByName('dicom')).LoadFromFile(p1); //-->Error Here
           Post;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quote marks from your string. It should be:

```
'C:\Compartilhada\dicomserver versoes\dicomserverx\data\Genesis-1000\1.2.410.200013.1.215.1.200912141600580009_0001_000001_13061821270002.dcm'
```

You might use `"` for paths containing spaces in some situations, for instance a command interpreter. But at the API level, it is simply not needed. And indeed it is a mistake as you have discovered. The double quote character `"` is actually a reserved character in a file name. That is documented on MSDN:

[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces: Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions)

> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:
>
> - ...
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), **except for the following**:
>
>   - The following reserved characters:
>
>     - < (less than)
>     - > (greater than)
>     - : (colon)
>     - **" (double quote)**
>     - / (forward slash)
>     - \ (backslash)
>     - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>     - ? (question mark)
>     - * (asterisk)
>   - ...
> - ...

---

In comments below you indicate that the code in the question does not reflect your actual problem. Which makes me wonder how you expect us to help. Your real problem is not the error message produced by the specific code, but that your debugging skills are letting you down. Let me try to explain how to debug a problem like this.

First of all, you are passing a file name to `LoadFromFile` or `TFileStream.Create`. These calls fail with an error that indicates that the file name is not valid.

So, when faced with that knowledge, the first step is to check the value of the file name that you are passing. Use debugging techniques to do that. Either the IDE debugger, or logging.

Once you have identified what value you are actually passing to these functions you can try to work out what is invalid about it.

To repeat, your real problem is not with the specifics, but in your debugging skills. You should take this as an opportunity to learn more about debugging. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for debugging. Learn to debug better, and your life as a programmer will become very much easier.

Comment: Mr David HefferMan. I simplified the post only to show the error. Can I complement it with more informations? My file names are filled into a Tstringlist and after it I loop into file names to load the files.

Comment: Did I not answer the question that you asked? Is there a different problem that you didn't ask?

Comment: My file name are filled from here:var sl:TstringList;
p1,p2:integer;
ss,fn:string;
OpenImageEnDialog1:TOpenImageEnDialog;
if OpenImageEnDialog1.Execute then begin
    OpenImageEnDialog1.files.Delimiter:='|';
    fn:=OpenImageEnDialog1.files.DelimitedText;
    sl:=TStringList.Create;
    p1:=1; p2:=1;
    while p2<=length(fn) do begin
     if (fn[p2]='|') then
     begin
       ss:=trim(copy(fn,p1,p2-p1));
       sl.Add( ss );
       p1:=p2+1;
     end;
     inc(p2);
    end;
    if (p1<>p2) then begin
     ss:=trim(copy(fn,p1,p2-p1+1));
     sl.Add( ss );
    end;
end;

Comment: Next, I use: for p1:=0 to sl.Count-1 do   begin
     with clds_dicom do begin
           Append;
           TBlobField(FieldByName('dicom')).LoadFromFile(sl[p1]);
           Post;
    end;
end;

Comment: Well, I'm going to stick to the question that you asked. If the question that you asked bears no relation to your actual problem, what are we supposed to do? Sigh.

Comment: I am not modifying the full name filled with the routine showed. Is a delphi bug when I fill the string list with full names?

Comment: I need get full names of dicom files of a directory and load each one into my image components. As TOpenImageEnDialog returns the file names separated with '|', I am looping it to get the full names. The loop is working well. The final file names in stringlist is something as '"C:\...."'

Comment: Did you read the second part of my answer, the part where I attempt to teach you how to debug?

Comment: Mr David, I know to debug. The problem is the space in name of the folder. If I get rid off the space all works well. I also tried replace " with double single quotes, but the error is the same. If I use  '"C:\Compartilhada\dicomserver_versoes\dicomserverx\data\Genesis-1000\1.2.410.200013.1.215.1.200912141600580009_0001_000001_13061821270002.dcm"' all works well(i change the folder dicomserver versoes to dicomserver_versoes(with underscore)

Comment: There's really no point in continuing this conversation. You have not listened to a word I said. I answered the question that you asked, that cannot be denied. Since you already know how to debug, I suggest you get on with solving the problem.

Comment: This is not a problem of debug. I know do that. It´s a problem with space in directory names and LoadfomStream

Comment: Do read my answer again, and try to absorb what I am telling you. Do not wrap your file name in quotes. Obviously you are very confused and believe that you need to do so when there are spaces in the filename. But you are wrong. Very badly wrong. Remove all the quotes. Get the file name right. And slow down and think harder. Look at your second comment below my answer and tell me that you were thinking clearly when you wrote that. Compare that to the second part of my answer where I explain how to debug such problems. Simplify.

Comment: Thank you very much. "Do not wrap your file name in quotes" It solves the problem"

Comment: Sigh. That was the very first sentence in the answer. I do think that there's a bigger picture to consider here. You think that you know how to debug, but I think you are deluding yourself. You might not want to hear that but the signs are clear to see.

Comment: Mr David, English is not my native language. I am doing my better to write the questions. Thank you.